# Go labstack/echo and OpenTelemetry doesn't work

Tags: go, open-telemetry, go-echo, otel

I'm trying to add otel tracing to my Echo server. I'm basing my code on [example](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-go-contrib/blob/main/instrumentation/github.com/labstack/echo/otelecho/example/server.go) but anything is not coming from application to Jaeger instance that i'm running locally.

First, I've injected the middleware

```
e := echo.New()
e.Validator = validator
e.HTTPErrorHandler = handlers.CustomHTTPErrorHandler

// Applying middleware
e.Use(echozap.ZapLogger(logger))
e.Use(middleware.Recover())
e.Use(echoprometheus.NewMiddleware("http"))
e.Use(middleware.RequestID())
e.Use(otelecho.Middleware("http"))

// ... rest of server initialization stuff
```

In my CustomHTTPErrorHandler I've put these lines

```
ctx := c.Request().Context()
trace.SpanFromContext(ctx).RecordError(err)
```

Also, in my main.go file I've initialized the tracer by calling `otel.Tracer("my_app")`.

As you can guess my app is not in a single file but has several packages, the one that I'm initializing HTTP server is `httpserver`. Instrumentation should work OOTB, I don't want to create spans for each endpoint. How can I achieve automatic instrumentation?

Comment: Did you setup an SDK and [register it globally](https://pkg.go.dev/go.opentelemetry.io/otel#SetTracerProvider)? Another option is to pass your `TracerProvider` directly using [`WithTracerProvider`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/github.com/labstack/echo/otelecho#WithTracerProvider)